# How to understand error network in Javascript Get request?

Tags: javascript, get

I try to run a GET request in Javascript but I've got a "network error"

```
var whatlinkshere = new XMLHttpRequest();
whatlinkshere.open("GET", "https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=linkshere&titles=Notebook_(programmation)&format=json", false) ;
whatlinkshere.send();
```

I've got the following error :

```
Error: A network error occurred.
```

Any solution ?

Comment: I think the issue is because the response from the server doesn't have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header present.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I address this issue ?